# How to integrate a python interface on website

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery, interface

I made a Python interface and I'm trying to integrate it to a HTML/CSS website in a `<div>`, but I have no idea about how to do it.

Any idea? Do you know any solution ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you explain what you mean with "python interface"?

Answer (score 1):

If you built a *command-line interface* (CLI) to your app, then you can expose it to the Internet via web framework like [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/) in form of REST API. Then you can access it with JavaScript on the frontend side.

But If you've built a *graphical user interface* (GUI) using framework like Tkinter, it is nearly impossible to transfer it to the web page without rewriting the code. [Anvil](https://anvil.works/blog/build-a-web-ui-with-python) seems to be able to provide web a GUI for Python, but I haven't tried it yet.